# Do while loop error message

Tags: java

I am a beginner programmer (first post here!) and I cannot figure out how to create an error message with a "do while" loop. If given input that's not in the alphabet it is supposed to display the error message until given an input with only letters and then move on the to rest of the program. My code seems to loop forever even if given correct input. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! :)

```
do {
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");  
    if (input.contains("[a-zA-Z]"))  
        name = input;
    else
         System.out.println("Please enter a valid name containing: ‘a-z’ or ‘A-Z’ lower or upper case");
} while (!input.contains("[a-zA-Z]"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the wrong method to validate your *regex*. `.contains()` expects a char sequence. That is not what you want. 
You should instead use the `.matches()` method.

```
String input = "";
do{
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");  
    if (input.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))  // Replacing the contains()
        name = input;
      else
         System.out.println
    ("Please enter a valid name containing: ‘a-z’ or ‘A-Z’ lower or upper case");
}while (!input.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")); //Once again replacing contains()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can show user an error popup so he knows something is wrong with his/her input.

In else statement where you are Printing message just do

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
"Please enter a valid name containing: ‘a-z’ or ‘A-Z’ lower or upper case.",
"Input error",
JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

return;
```

[For more information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

`String.contains()` method matches a set of character sequence.
What you've specified is a regular expression, hence, you should be using `String.matches()` or the `Pattern` class to perform the check.

It should be something like this using the `Pattern` class.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if(m.matches){
 //Do something
}
```

Refer to this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

`input.contains("[a-zA-Z]")` checks if input contains the text [a-zA-Z].

You can use the [matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) method.

```
input.matches("[a-zA-z]+")
```

Also, you should use [a-zA-z]+ as the pattern, since you are trying to match one or more alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to how you check for the given input.

```
 String input;
        String name = "";
        do {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");
            if (input.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
                name = input;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid name containing: ‘a-z’ or ‘A-Z’ lower or upper case");
            }
        } while (!input.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"));
```

using the **matches** function of string can help you achieve what you want